# Double is NaN, but it shouldn't

Tags: java

Hello I'm new with Java and I don't understand why my Programm outputs NaN twice!

Here's the Code. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Inputs I gave
were 2,3,3
(A is 2 B is 3 C is 3)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("A :");
    double a = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nB :");
    double b = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nC :");
    double c = scan.nextDouble();


    double temp = Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c);
    double result_one = (-1*b+ temp)/(2*a);
    double result_two=(-1*b- temp)/2*a;


    System.out.println("The Result for A:" +a +" B:" +b +" C:" +c +" is");
    System.out.println("Result 1 : " + result_one);//This double Should not be NaN
    System.out.println("Result 2 : " + result_two);//This double Should not be NaN
}
```

Comment: You should also share your input for `a`, `b` and `c` that causes NaN.

Comment: What inputs are you giving the program?

Comment: @Fred2  Inputs I gave were 2,3,3 (A is 2 B is 3 C is 3)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, as the OP used the wrong value for B - it should be 9, not 3, as per the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical Quadratic equation. Your problem is caused by the `temp` variable. The value of `b*b` is smaller than `4*a*c`, so it would mean that you try to extract the square root of a negative number.

Try printing the temp variable and depending on your input you will get the same `NaN` message. Basically, the message is caused by the fact that your problem is not solvable using "real" numbers.

You should read about [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) numbers.

As suggested by @michalk in the comment, you can read about the [Math.sqrt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-) function.

Since you didn't add the values when I answered the question, I am editing this answer to explicitly explain why it is not working:

1. You are trying to solve: `a * x^2 + b * x + c = 0` or `2 * x^2 + 3 * x + 3 = 0`
2. The necessary condition to solve the equation is `b^2 - 4*a*c >= 0` or `3*3 - 4*2*3 > 0`
   =>
   The necessary condition is not achieved since `-15 < 0`

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-):

> Returns: 
>   the positive square root of a. If the argument is NaN or less
>   than zero, the result is NaN.

Comment: You are probably right. Also you could attach link to [`Math.sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-)  method. Documentation of this method crealry states when a `NaN` could be returned.

Comment: I used the Same inputs as given in the Tutorial I watched, I checked the code but mine just dont seem to work as his even though the codes are the same. For the Inputs 2,3,3 I should get 2 Real Number Solutions(The Tutorial I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mx6rGP6jiQ go to 10:35 to see that 2,3,3 has 2 real Number Solutions)

Comment: @itzChris: The value of `b` at 10:35 is 9, not 3. Listen at 10:12.

Comment: @itzChris I edited the answer so that it matches your input. I also explained it from the math perspective. The value in your answer is different than the one in the video

Comment: @itzChris If you have any other questions we can move to the chat, but if everything is now clear, please accept my answer since it was improved and it contains both the explanation and the math reasoning behind it

Answer (score 1):

You are actually getting the error `NaN` (Not a Number) from this line -

```
double temp = Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c);
```

cause (`3*3-4*2*3`) gives `-15`. The square root of a negative number giving you a `NaN`. So you are getting `NaN`twice.

You could try the following code snippet to get a correct result -

```
        double temp = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;

        System.out.println("The Result for A:" +a +" B:" +b +" C:" +c +" is");
        if (temp > 0.0) {
            double result_one = (-b + Math.pow(result, 0.5)) / (2.0 * a);
            double result_two = (-b - Math.pow(result, 0.5)) / (2.0 * a);
            System.out.println("Result 1 : " + result_one);                
            System.out.println("Result 2 : " + result_two);
        } else if (temp == 0.0) {
            double result_one = -b / (2.0 * a);
            System.out.println("The root is " + result_one);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The equation has no real roots.");
        }
```

Comment: @LoolKovsky: For one thing, it offers alternative code. It's fine to have multiple answers which explain the problem. There's no problem here.

Comment: @LoolKovsky, here I didn't take a square root, just raise the power to 0.5 which is equivalent to square root. You also can use square root function here because before square rooting I've checked whether it is greater than `0.0`

Comment: @JonSkeet It was edited, in the beginning, it didn't contain the code. It was just the calculation of the delta factor. :)

Comment: @LoolKovsky: It was edited before your comment though - if you're going to complain about timelines, you need to be consistent :) Basically people can work on answers (and comments) at the same time. There's no problem here - the world is a better place for multiple answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, it is my bad :) I was not complaining, I was just explaining the reason I added the comment in the first place.